# How to simply group static/constant values into one "namespace"

Tags: javascript, typescript

Imagine you want to put all the endpoint URL's of your application into one file. The general aim is to be able to use these URL's like so:

```js
import { Endpoints } from "./Endpoints";

Endpoints.APP_BASE_URL
Endpoints.ORDER
Endpoints.BOOKS
```

Just **one named import** to access all the endpoint URL's. Also the URL's are **dependent on each other** (this will get clearer below), which is why an `enum` is not sufficient.

## Option 1: abstract classes

```js
export abstract class Endpoints {
  public static APP_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:7777/";
  public static BOOKS = `${Endpoints.APP_BASE_URL}books/`;
  public static ORDERS = `${Endpoints.APP_BASE_URL}orders/`;
}
```

**Downside:** Misuse of a `class`.

## Option 2: group exports

```js
const APP_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:7777/";
const BOOKS = `${APP_BASE_URL}books/`;
const ORDERS = `${APP_BASE_URL}orders/`;

export const Endpoints = { APP_BASE_URL, BOOKS, ORDERS };
```

**Downside:** *Error prone* and *duplication* because you always have to write the endpoints twice.

## Option 3: index file

```js
export const APP_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:7777/";
export const BOOKS = `${APP_BASE_URL}books/`;
export const ORDERS = `${APP_BASE_URL}orders/`;
```

```js
// index.ts/js
import * as Endpoints from "./Endpoints";

export { Endpoints };
```

**Downside:** One extra file for a simple issue.

## Question

Is there another way of grouping static/constant values beside of the 3 mentioned options above, that has ideally no downside?
If there is no other option, which option is the most *javascripty/typescripty* one?

(Please don't focus on the endpoints example, it could also be numbers, objects or anything else)

Comment: Your analysis of the downsides is solid. A plain object would be the most expedient.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so you mean option 2?

Comment: Basically option 2, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following documentation pages:
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

From the first page you can add another option:
Using the namespace keyword. However, since you're using the native modules it makes little sense to do that, as the documentation also mentions - see the "Needless Namespacing" section.
And it also provides the correct solution to your problem, which you also touched, but for some reason added the extra file:

```
import * as Endpoints from "./Endpoints";
```

Relevant excerpt from the documentation:

> A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules
>   will never contribute names to the same scope. Because the consumer of
>   a module decides what name to assign it, there’s no need to
>   proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a namespace.
>
> To reiterate why you shouldn’t try to namespace your module contents,
>   the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical grouping of
>   constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the module file
>   itself is already a logical grouping, and its top-level name is
>   defined by the code that imports it, it’s unnecessary to use an
>   additional module layer for exported objects.

Comment: I'm well aware of this export syntax and I really don't like to use it in my applications (only when third party libraries are forcing me to do so..). The reason for that is that **autocomplete for the import statemant is non-existent** (e.g. if you start typing "Enpoints" you get no suggestion) and you can **potentially import it with a different name** in every file (same for default export which I also don't like). This is why I highlighted: **one named import**. Autocomplete will work perfect and you can not accidently name it different (e.g. `import * from Enpdoints`)

Comment: No autocomplete? Are you using Visual Code or something else? 
Also, not sure importing with a different name in every file is really a big issue. Unless you're exporting something, whatever happens in a file should stay in that file. For consistency concerns, you could try to import under the same name as the file itself.

Comment: yea I am using VS Code + react + typescript and I never get autocomplete for `* as anything from "anything"` when I start typing "anything". I need to type the import statement manually everytime .. maybe I am just stupid :) For me importing same thing differently makes no real sense.. it's just harder to read and maintain in the end .. default export makes also no real sense since there are aliases anyway.. I dont say it's ultra bad and that I can't live with it, but that's just MHO though

Comment: I actually do get autocomplete in VS Code + typescript, so really not sure what you're doing wrong there.